# linux - export tree directory list with links to file

Tags: python, linux, bash, comparison, diff

I am trying to create a comparision report between two directories. with `diff2html.py` I have exported the files with difference as html, which looks like. 
[image: diff2html output for a file with difference]

with the `tree` command I am able to export the directory structure to html, but the exported does not look formatted as in `TOhtml` does in `vimdiff`. Would it be possible to expor the directory along with hyperlinks for the files, like below[image]

is there a plugin that does this,do I miss any command that can do this

Comment: would you please let me know if my question is not descriptive? after marking it down please

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a folder comparision report, like the one generated by beyond compare or araxis. I dont have xwindow and need to do it only using command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse of the output of the tree command it is not difficult. You can substitute the special chars by space:

```
tree|tr '└─├└│' ' '
```

Then just by reading file line by line, make stack and if there is not more spaces then on the line before delete last line in the stack, finally in both cases add current line in to the stack.

Then you can use python library xml.etree, make new document and add there roots by the reading lines, the count of spaces means the depth in the document. You get the link just by reading the stack.

If you need more info about anything here, just leave here a comment.